# Magento Templates change

Tags: template

unfortunately I can not use new template anymore. I have the following entry under 
`system -> provided -> design (see picture)`.

I have entered this without start and end date. Now I can not select a new template anymore or unused.

I can also under `System -> Configuration -> Design` select other templates.

What  can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply click on the row from the screenshot, enter an end date and save or simply delete the entry entirely.